# Selected dropdown value is NULL when i read it in views.py

Tags: python, html, django, drop-down-menu, django-views

I have taken some input from the user and stored it in Django SQLite file and same data is fetching it and displaying in dropdown list but when the user selects a value, the selected value is coming as null to the views.py.

I have tried using POST.get also but still, I'm getting NULL from the form. Can anyone of you help me to identify my mistakes?

HTML FILE:

```
 <form method="post" action="/NewHandBook/ReadCobrand">{% csrf_token %}

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="margin-top: 5px">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li class="dropdown" style="padding-right: 10px">
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="font-family: Courier">
                                    <option name="NewEnvName"
                                            value="xyz">xyz</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown" style="font-family: Courier;font-size: 20px;color: ivory">

                            <input type='radio' name='CobranSelection' value="CobrandName" checked/>
                            <label for="edit-radios-lorem-tortor-erat" class="option"
                            >Cobrand
                                Name | </label>
                            <input type='radio' name='CobranSelection' value="CobrandId"/>
                            <label for="edit-radios-lorem-tortor-erat" class="option"
                            >Cobrand
                                Id </label>

                        </li>
                    </ul>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text"
                               style="margin-top: -1px;font-family: Courier;width: 210px;margin-right: -10px"
                               class="form-control"
                               name="cobrand" placeholder="Eneter Cobrand detail here">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
                                style="margin-top: -31px;font-family: Courier;margin-left: 230px">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>


                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('login', views.login),
    url('Home', views.fetch_all_env),
    url('AddEnvironment', views.add_environment),
    url('GetEnvironment', views.GetEnvironment),
    url('ReadDb', views.readdb),
    url('LearnCobrand', views.learncobrand),
    url('ReadCobrand',views.knowcobrand)
]
```

views.py

```
def knowcobrand(request):
    value_type = request.POST.get('CobranSelection')
    cobrand_value = request.POST.get('cobrand')
    env = request.POST.get('NewEnvName')
    print(value_type)
    print(cobrand_value)
    print(env)
    return render(request, 'CobrandView/CobrandInDepth.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

[You're looking for a ChoiceField which renders as a select html element by default.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield)

[Also make sure to check this, it's a more comprehensive guide of what you want](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response...I have gone through your doc and looks like even im using request.POST.get to get the value but still im getting null. Are you able to find something